# Lazy loading not working after being configured

Tags: angular

I have tried and configured lazy loading in my angular 10 application but the blank page loads. I have written a console.log in the ngOnit of the child component which never fires. Could somebody tell me what is the problem. As you can see below i am trying to lazyload the CustomerOrdersComponent component. I dont see any errors in the console tab and neither a call to the url in the network tab

app.routing.module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { CustomerDetailsComponent } from '../app/modules/customer/components/customer-details/customer-details.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'customers', component: CustomerDetailsComponent },
  { path: 'orders', loadChildren: () => import('./modules/order/order.module').then(m => m.OrderModule) }

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

AppModule

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    CustomerModule,
    SharedModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Order-routing module

```
const orderRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'orders', component: CustomerOrdersComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'orderDetails', component: OrderDetailsComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(orderRoutes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class OrderRoutingModule { }
```

order module

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    CustomerOrdersComponent,
    OrderDetailsComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    OrderRoutingModule
  ]
})
export class OrderModule { }
```

CustomerOrders component

```
export class CustomerOrdersComponent implements OnInit {

  customerOrders: ICustomerOrders[];

  constructor(private customerOrdersService: CustomerOrdersService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log('Order component getting called');
    this.getCustomerOrders();
  }


  getCustomerOrders(): void {
      this.customerOrdersService.getCustomerOrders().subscribe( data => this.customerOrders = data);
  }

}
```

Comment: Can you post the command that navigate to orders please? Does it execute when you breakpoint there?

Comment: Your route for CustomersOrdersComponent is orders/orders. Is this intentional? Wouldn’t you like the nested route to be just an empty string?

Comment: i would just want only /orders

Comment: So change “orders” in the nested routing module to “”. What happens now?

Comment: YOu mean like this  {
    path: '', component: CustomerOrdersComponent
  },

Comment: How will the route know that it needs to look at empty string for orders

Comment: That behavior happens by default, by default it looks for empty string. I'll post an answer with it. If it works please give credit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update you nested Route configuration from:

```
{
    path: 'orders', component: CustomerOrdersComponent
},
```

to an empty path:

```
{
    path: '', component: CustomerOrdersComponent
},
```

By default, the router looks for empty path.

Now the validation should work because the path to reach `CustomerOrdersComponent` is `/orders` and not `orders/orders`.

Answer (score 0):

Configure your **OrderRoutingModule** like below

```
 const orderRoutes: Routes = [    
  {
    path: '', component: CustomerOrdersComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'orderDetails', component: OrderDetailsComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(orderRoutes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class OrderRoutingModule { }
```

By using the above changes in OrderRoutingModule your routing will start working as expected. Because the first entry point is empty.

Comment: This is just what I wrote in one of the comments and I was waiting for @Tom to respond. I'll now write an answer for it.

Comment: I didn't see your comments before you posting my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Update your nested Route configuration from:

```
{
    path: 'orders', component: CustomerOrdersComponent
},
```

to an empty path:

```
{
    path: '', component: CustomerOrdersComponent
},
```

By default, the router looks for an empty path.

Now the validation should work because the path to reach CustomerOrdersComponent is /orders and not orders/orders.